# What are my options to temporarily seal a hole behind piping, before doing a more permenant fix?

Tags: crack, hole-repair

I am filling some deep holes and holes behind piping.  I just want to fill it with something temporary as it is releasing mould however my landlord will do a permanent repair with something of their choosing at a later date.

What can we seal it with temporarily that can be easily removed when it comes to doing the permanent repair?

Thanks.

Comment: **I am not a attorney** but i would think that any proof that the holes are causing harm should be established **before you alter them**. Once you modify the holes you have placed your claims in jeopardy.   **Get a lawyer before you do anything**. Filling holes, covering holes and making holes is pretty straight forward. **You have not given us any information on what  the holes are in, what kind of holes and how big they are**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves preservation of evidence, which s a question for OP’s lawyer and technical consultant, not us.

Comment: You've asked a _whole bunch_ of questions over the last few days relating to your sensitivities. Each individual question has, on the whole, been a reasonable one to ask. When taken together, however, it seems that you have a much bigger issue to deal with and maybe you need to take a step back to see how you can address your living situation as a whole. I am, by no means a Dr., nor am I trying to discourage you from asking questions, but I think you may need to look at the big picture instead of all the little parts. [Con't...]

Comment: Please forgive me if you have done so and these questions are the result of that big picture review. Again, your questions _are_ welcome, I'm just trying to ensure that you're getting the help you need, which may be way beyond the abilities of this site.

Comment: @FreeMan Naturally I am in contact with my doctor/legal team with the issues relevant to them.  However what I have asked in all my questions is home improvement regardless of the context behind them. I will have to do these repairs anyway.  The only reason I mentioned the background in this case is because someone(Solar Mike) might have shot me down and said 'do it properly' or 'why would you want to 'make it and break it'.  I could have just rephrased question as temo fix. Solar Mike, if you are seeing this I'm just kidding.  Mike is a good chap, he helped me tonnes over at mechanics.

Comment: Just checking... Glad to hear you're looking at the whole picture.

Answer (score 2):

Drill around the perimeter of the hole and hit in the middle with a hammer. You might want to get some air tests first before filling in the holes. If this is a rental, you need to put the landlord on notice. If you think your health is in danger and willing stay there, you are weakening your case. don't do any work filling unless you get approval from landlord. they could say you caused the problem.

Comment: Jack why do you say that.  Is it because sealing damp will exacerbate it?  Even so doesn't mean I caused it, If I put landlord on notice then cover it for relief I was obviously already there?

Comment: @JamesWilson   Have you ever been in a legal dispute?  They, lawyers, will say anything. They could say the fillers interacted with the wood or paint. If you put the landlord on notice and get permission to fill, you should be ok.

Comment: @james If you are renting, you mangle with someone else's property. Would you do some work on another person's car without getting permission?

Answer (score 1):

Fill the holes around the pipes with the copper mesh (or copper wool) used to exclude rodents. This is packed in and can be later pulled out.

Comment: It sees these would not create an air tight seal?

Comment: Then use expanding spray foam.

Comment: can the spray foam be easily removed/pulled out?  How would one go about doing it?  Thanks.